# Prevent console error with Mongoose, node and graphql

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, apollo

I'm making an API server with Express, Graphql (Apollo server) and mongoose.

I'm testing the user creation. When the email is duplicated mongoose throws an error (Validation error. Unique = true) and graphql handles very good. But the console (terminal) shows the error too. How can i prevent that issue?

Resolver:

```
const MODEL_PATH = '../../models';
const User = require(MODEL_PATH + '/User');
const { register } = require('../../controllers/auth/RegisterController');

module.exports = {
  RootQuery: {
    users() {
      return User.find({});
    }
  },
  Mutation: {
    registerUser(_, data) {
      return register(data);
    }
  }
};
```

RegisterController (register function)

```
exports.register = function(data) {
  const { email, password } = data;

  const user = new User({
    email,
    password
  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    user.save().then((user) => {
      resolve(user);
    }).catch((err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });

};
```

And the error in the console (I DON'T WANT THAT. I HANDLED THE ERROR IN THE CONTROLLER. I WANT THE ERROR ONLY IN THE GRAPHQL RESPONSE)

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: y.users index: email_1 dup key: { : "test@example.com" }
    at Function.MongoError.create (/Volumes/Datos/x/code/y/server/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at toError (/Volumes/Datos/x/code/y/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:114:22)
   ....
```

Response in Graphiql (That is ok)

```
{
  "data": {
    "registerUser": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: y.users index: email_1 dup key: { : \"test@example.com\" }",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 9,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "registerUser"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

According to: http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-server/setup.html

in server

```
app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({ schema: myschema, debug: false }));
```

debug false did the trick.

Now. I'm check the packages for better error handling

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check out `apollo-errors`:

https://github.com/thebigredgeek/apollo-errors

and `apollo-resolvers`:

https://github.com/thebigredgeek/apollo-resolvers

These packages, together, were made to handle issues like the one you describe